# Inconsistent slow performance of Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an API endpoint, which only perform read request. Usually, the entire operation can be completed under 100ms

```
[03/Aug/2015:19:35:53 -0700] "GET /query?email=xxx%40aol.com&hash=xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 186 - "myapp-1.0.6o" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=74 cpu_ms=27 cpm_usd=0.000021 instance=00c61b117c55f2b00cdd73904665675ced040765 app_engine_release=1.9.24
```

However, it is not uncommon I can see some request, surge up to 20 seconds!

```
[03/Aug/2015:18:59:50 -0700] "GET /query?email=yyy%40gmail.com&hash=yyy HTTP/1.1" 200 193 - "myapp-1.0.6o" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=18288 cpu_ms=61 cpm_usd=0.000022 instance=00c61b117c55f2b00cdd73904665675ced040765 app_engine_release=1.9.24
```

Now, the server load is still pretty light. It gets 1 - 5 requests within a minute. We still fall under free quota usage.

The API python code is pretty straight forward. I don't think it is the culprit of such slow operation.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty(required = True)

class QueryHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        email = self.request.get('email')
        hash = self.request.get('hash')
        expected_hash = Utils.hash(email)

        result = {
            'email' : email,
            'user_timestamp' : 0,
            'server_timestamp' : 0,
            'free_trial_duration' : _FREE_TRIAL_DURATION
        }

        user_timestamp = 0

        if hash == expected_hash:
            user_timestamp = memcache.get(email)

            if user_timestamp is None:                
                user = User.get_by_id(email)
                if user is not None:
                    user_timestamp = int(time.mktime(user.timestamp.timetuple()))
                    result['user_timestamp'] = user_timestamp
                    memcache.add(email, user_timestamp, _MEMCACHE_DURATION)
            else:
                result['user_timestamp'] = user_timestamp

        else:
            logging.debug('QueryHandler, email = ' + email + ', hash = ' + hash + ', expected_hash = ' + expected_hash)

        server_timestamp = max(int(time.time()), user_timestamp)
        result['server_timestamp'] = server_timestamp
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        json_result = json.encode(result)
        self.response.out.write(json_result)
        logging.debug('QueryHandler, result = ' + json_result)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/query', QueryHandler),
], debug=False)
```

It seems more to Google App Engine server quality. Is there anything we can do, to avoid unreasonable slowness of API consumption?

Comment: Is this local or on App Engine?  What does [Cloud Trace](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-trace/) tell you? Are the slow requests associated with loading new instances?

Comment: That's weird. Under Monitoring -> Traces -> Settings, "Debug latency and performance" is shown as ON. But, in Monitoring -> Traces -> Trace List, no traces were found.